# How to set a delay on audio in android studio?

Tags: java, android, string, audio, delay

My issue with this code is that all my audio files play at the same time. I'm attempting to create an application that plays a computed song based on what you type in the EDITTEXT. I need a way to delay each subsequent note a certain amount of time so that it plays like a song... Is there any way to do this without having more case statements.

My java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


EditText edit;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edit  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box);
    button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String string = edit.getText().toString();
            char arr[]=string.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                switch (arr[i]) {
                    case 'a':
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample);
                        mp.start();

                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample1);
                        mp1.start();

                        break;
                    case 'c':
                        MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample2);
                        mp2.start();

                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample3);
                        mp3.start();

                        break;
                    case 'e':
                        MediaPlayer mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample4);
                        mp4.start();

                        break;
                    case 'f':
                        MediaPlayer mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample5);
                        mp5.start();

                        break;
                    case 'g':
                        MediaPlayer mp6 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample6);
                        mp6.start();

                        break;
                    case 'h':
                        MediaPlayer mp7 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample);
                        mp7.start();

                        break;
                    case 'i':
                        MediaPlayer mp8 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample1);
                        mp8.start();

                        break;
                    case 'j':
                        MediaPlayer mp9 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample2);
                        mp9.start();

                        break;
                    case 'k':
                        MediaPlayer mp10 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample3);
                        mp10.start();

                        break;
                    case 'l':
                        MediaPlayer mp11 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample4);
                        mp11.start();

                        break;
                    case 'm':
                        MediaPlayer mp12 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample5);
                        mp12.start();

                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        MediaPlayer mp13 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample6);
                        mp13.start();

                        break;
                    case 'o':
                        MediaPlayer mp14 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample);
                        mp14.start();

                        break;
                    case 'p':
                        MediaPlayer mp15 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample1);
                        mp15.start();

                        break;
                    case 'q':
                        MediaPlayer mp16 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample2);
                        mp16.start();

                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        MediaPlayer mp17 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample3);
                        mp17.start();

                        break;
                    case 's':
                        MediaPlayer mp18 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample4);
                        mp18.start();

                        break;
                    case 't':
                        MediaPlayer mp19 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample5);
                        mp19.start();

                        break;
                    case 'u':
                        MediaPlayer mp20 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample6);
                        mp20.start();

                        break;
                    case 'v':
                        MediaPlayer mp21 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample);
                        mp21.start();

                        break;
                    case 'w':
                        MediaPlayer mp22 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample2);
                        mp22.start();

                        break;
                    case 'x':
                        MediaPlayer mp23 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample3);
                        mp23.start();

                        break;
                    case 'y':
                        MediaPlayer mp24 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample4);
                        mp24.start();

                        break;
                    case 'z':
                        MediaPlayer mp25 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample5);
                        mp25.start();

                        break;
                    case ' ':
                        MediaPlayer mp26 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sample6);
                        mp26.start();

                        break;
                }
```

I want a function that will allow me to have multiple audio files all delayed at a certain point so that they dont play at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `MediaPlayer.onCompletionListener` to listen to the event when a track ends. The next audio file will play after this. An example

```
mp.prepare();
mp1.prepare();   
mp.start();
mp.setNextMediaPlayer(mp1);
```

**EDIT**

To play multiple audio files one after the other, you don't have to create nested onCompletionListener one after the other. You could simply create an array of all the audio files you want to play and set onCompletionListener. An example:

```
int[] myAudio = {R.raw.audio1, R.raw.audio2, R.raw.audio3};
int mTrackFinish = 0;
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myAudio[0]);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
{
 @Override
 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
 {
     mTrackFinish++;
     mp.reset();
     if(mTrackFinish < myAudio.length)
            // play some audio from list
        else
          mTrackFinish=0;
          mp.release();
          mp = null;  // either set counter to 0 and start again or call end of list

    }
});
mp.start();
```

Comment: that doesnt allow the next audio to play.

Comment: That allows for char "b" to play. And I want the next character in the series, regardless of what it is, to be prepared and played, subsequent to the previous.

Comment: I have edited the answer. This code will play multiple audios one after the other after completion.
P.S Suprising that the issue suddenly popped up after more than a month's time.